# What could happen if regex metacharacters using named capturing group are not encoded?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, java, encoding, validation

Let's say that a web application take a specific input from the user (e.g., search form), apply a Java regex with named caputring groups on it and use the final output to do other stuff (e.g., look for the searched resource which name has been modified through the regex).

What if some regex metacharacters, especially $ which is used in named capturing group to refer to the specific groups (e.g., $1 refers to group 1), are not encoded and a user could alterate the regex flow injecting them?

A little code example:

```
"aaaaaafooNfooaaaaaaa".replaceAll("foo([A-Z])foo", "user_input" )
```

The user, instead of "user_input", could insert $1 and recall the first capturing group. But this is just a simple and mere example, there could be lots of other kind of uses.

I can't really see any concrete security threat, apart from trying to manipulate the regex flow, but I wish to know if someone could.

Comment: In your example, are you simply trying to replace "fooNfoo" by "N"

Comment: Yes, but that's an example. My question is, what could a malicious user, who can control regex metacharecters such as $, do? Is there any possibility tu evaluate code or things like that?

Comment: Nothing? Regex replacing usually work like this. You have 3 inputs : "your_input", "pattern" and "replacement". The "pattern" is usually fixed and hardcoded into your code and that's the only place where the regex metacharacter have any meaning, so no a user cannot manipulate how the regex work, unless you let him set the "pattern".

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was the point :). Because of i have never used named capturing groups in java i didn't know if they could open way to bad things, such as for example code evaluation etc. However, the replacement was just an example to clarify the concept. My question was more generic, addressed to all kind of regex where an user can control some metacharcters. I obviously know that it depends on which part of the regex the user can control and even on what the final regex output is used for...but maybe someone had already addressed similar problems ;)

Comment: @Gudradain: Not true, `$1` will refer to the first group so it does have special meaning in the replacement.

Comment: @SilverlightFox No. Regex metacharacter have no meaning unless they are in the pattern. Here the pattern is "foo[A-Z]foo" and the replacement is "user_input". The user can put $1 in the replacement or any other string with special meaning, it doesn't matter since it's just in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, there is a very minor data leakage vulnerability here.

In your example:

```
"aaaaaafooNfooaaaaaaa".replaceAll("foo([A-Z])foo", "user_input")
```

if `user_input` contained `$1` and the value of the above was output and the input string `aaaaaafooNfooaaaaaaa` was not user controlled, the user would be able to find out what the original "secret" string was (i.e. the `N`).

Practically the answer is really no, unless someone has been deliberately "unusual" with their coding.